# Get NPK values of soil without spectroscopy

Tags: data-analysis, field-measurements, soil-science, nutrient-cycles

I stumbled upon this new device called **[Teralytic](https://teralytic.com/)**. Which can measure salination, NPK values and all sorts of things.

Unfortunately it's sold out and I think when it'll be available again rather expensive. So I as a hobbymaker thought maybe I can build something like this myself? So I was wondering how do they measure these things rigth in the soil itself? The only thing that might be helpful is [this](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/8312001) but It doesn't say wheter they used prepared soil samples or just a nomral earth right from their garden or somewhere. Does anyone maybe have an Idea how they could've done it? What techniques have they used?

Comment: The site gives no information that I could find on what type of sensors they are using. Thus it is impossible to determine how to replicate it. There are a number of companies marketing sensors for do-it-yourself IoT systems so you could start there.

Comment: Well thats why i was asking because they don't share any information